# Syntax error on token "module", interface expected

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

Getting the following error on java 9 project in vscode. Code builds on maven and executes successfully. The syntax error highlight is the only issue

vscode-spring-boot logs:

```
Activating 'vscode-spring-boot' extension
Found java exe: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10\bin\java.exe
isJavaEightOrHigher => true
Redirecting server logs to C:\Users\USER1\AppData\Local\Temp\vscode-spring-boot-1531299333218.log
ERR: Redirecting log output to: C:\Users\USER1\AppData\Local\Temp\vscode-spring-boot-1531299333218.log
ERR:
```

Child process connected on port 45556

```
Language support logs:
WARNING: Using incubator modules: jdk.incubator.httpclient
[Error - 2:25:48 PM] Jul 11, 2018, 2:25:38 PM Error occured while building workspace. Details: 
message: Syntax error on token "module", interface expected;code: 1610612940
message: Syntax error on token ".", , expected;code: 1610612940
message: Syntax error on token "module", interface expected;code: 1610612940
message: The project was not built since the source file /jdt.ls-java-project/src/com/demo/App.java could not be read;code: 0
```

Comment: I Recommended You to use an official Java IDEs
Like netbeans, eclipse,intellj

Comment: Please format this illegible mess.

Answer (score 0):

The project was a hello world maven project in java 9. Without the addition of these 3 property entries the maven plugin defaulted to java 1.5. After adding these properties in pom.xml and building the project the issue is fixed.

```
<maven.compiler.source>1.9</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>1.9</maven.compiler.target>
<maven.compiler.release>9</maven.compiler.release>
```